# setAllowsImageEditing is deprecated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting this warning when compiling the code, setAllowsImageEditing is deprecated.
Any help pls.

```
self.imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `allowsEditing` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

'Picker.allowsImageEditing' is deprecated from iOS 3.1. Use 'Picker.allowsEditing' instead.